# Getting error code 0xc004f210 when trying to activate Windows 10 with a Windows 8 product key

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation, product-key

I have a Lenovo G580 laptop that came with pre-loaded Windows 8 on it. I did a fresh install to Windows 10 using the Microsoft Media Creation Tool and rebooted then the installer asked me for the product key, so I entered my Windows 8 key (The one I found in the bios using a third party software) and it did not accept it, I clicked "I don't have a product key" and the installation continued. Then I tried again to activate Windows using my product key and I got error `0xc004f210` "You are running Windows 10 Home. The product key you entered cannot be used to activate this edition." I tried to install the pro edition and got the same error. Do I have to install Windows 8 again then upgrade to Windows 8.1 then again upgrade to Windows 10 or is there a solution to my issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are specific versions of your operating systems? You may have a mismatch...

Comment: EnisP.Aginić, Do you mean the Windows 8 version as in home or pro? I don't remember what the version was before I installed Windows 10 is there a way I can find out in the bios or something?

Comment: G series i most likely home edition, but it may be Windows 8 Home, Windows 8 Home Single Language, or maybe they have something else depending on your location. I suggest you give Microsoft support a call, they should be able to assist you better then us, as your problem may be region specific.

Comment: You cannot use Windows 8 key for Windows 10. You must install the OS which your laptop came with and then upgrade.

Comment: @vembutech not true, since W10 version 1511 you can use a qualifying key from W7 or W8

Answer (score 1):

You might see this error if you entered a product key for a different edition of Windows than the edition installed on your device. You might also see this error if you previously upgraded to Windows 10, but the current edition of Windows installed on your device doesn't match the edition of your digital entitlement.

You can either enter a valid product key that matches the edition of Windows installed on your device or re-install the edition of Windows 10 that matches your digital entitlement.